# Determine compass direction from one lat/lon to the other

Tags: algorithm, geospatial, pseudocode

Does anyone have an algorithm to determine the direction from one lat/lon to another (pseudo-code):

```
CalculateHeading( lat1, lon1, lat2, long2 ) returns string heading
```

Where heading is e.g. NW, SW, E, etc.

Basically, I have two points on a map and I want to get a general idea of the direction taking into account that 50 miles East and one mile North is simply East and not Northeast.

Comment: Where do you want the cut-off point to be for choosing between cardinal and intermediate directions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) has the basic algorithm:

```
// in javascript, not hard to translate...
var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -
        Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDeg();
```

UPDATED: See here for complete algorith [Mapping Math and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971585/mapping-math-and-javascript)

That'll give you a number between 0 and 360 then it's just a matter of having a simple lookup:

```
var bearings = ["NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N"];

var index = brng - 22.5;
if (index < 0)
    index += 360;
index = parseInt(index / 45);

return(bearings[index]);
```

It's important to note that your bearing actually changes as you move around the earth. The algorithm above shows you *initial* bearing, but if you're traveling a long distance, your bearing to be significantly different when you reach the destination (if you're only traveling a short distance [< a few hundred kms] then it probably won't change enough to be a concern).

Comment: The latitude and longitude inputs must be converted from degrees to radians before inputing them into these calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Do you remember your trig functions? I.e. SOHCAHTOA:

- **SOH**: Sin(θ) = Opposite over Hypotenuse
- **CAH**: Cos(θ) = Adjacent over Hypotenuse
- **TOA**: Tan(θ) = Opposite over Adjacent

In pseudo-code:

```
function getDir(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) {
    margin = π/90; // 2 degree tolerance for cardinal directions
    o = lat1 - lat2;
    a = long1 - long2;
    angle = atan2(o,a);

    if (angle > -margin && angle < margin):
            return "E";
    elseif (angle > π/2 - margin && angle < π/2 + margin):
            return "N";
    elseif (angle > π - margin && angle < -π + margin):
            return "W";
    elseif (angle > -π/2 - margin && angle < -π/2 + margin):
            return "S";
    }
    if (angle > 0 && angle < π/2) {
        return "NE";
    } elseif (angle > π/2 && angle < π) {
        return "NW";
    } elseif (angle > -π/2 && angle < 0) {
        return "SE";
    } else {
        return "SW";
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**
As Pete and Dean pointed out, this does not take into account the curvature of the Earth. For more accurate calculations for points away from the equator, you'll need to use [spherical triangle formulas](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Crs), as used in Dean's answer.

**Edit 2:**
Another correction; as Pete noted, `arctan()` does not give the correct angles, as -1/-1 and 1/1 are the same (as are -1/1 and 1/-1). [`arctan2(y, x)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) is a two argument variation of `arctan()` that is designed to compensate for this. `arctan()` has a range of (-π, π], positive for `y >= 0` and negative for `y < 0`.

Comment: Note this fails the "50 miles East and one mile North is simply East and not Northeast" requirement. It also assumes you're talking about a flat plane, rather than a sphere (but that might be OK if the distances are small).

Comment: @erickson: unfortunately, that doesn't work, or at least not in code blocks.

Comment: You probably want atan2 since -1/-1 is the opposite direction to 1/1, and this won't give anything like the correct angle except near the equator - at 60 north, north east would be about two degrees east for each degree north.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a numeric angle and use the result to look up the text. For example, -22.5..+22.5 = N. +22.5..67.5 = NE, 67.5..112.5 = E, etc. Of course, that's assuming you're using only N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW -- if you decide (for example) to go with the old "32 points of the compass", each text string obviously represents a smaller range.