# How to tell direction of two geo points

Tags: android, point, direction, geopoints

i've 3 geo points

(start Position)11.986242477259117, 79.84657287597656`

(middle position)11.984521304799278, 79.84583258628845

(end postion)11.985014568760436, 79.844491481781

I've get knowledge from [How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)

and i've drawed the line between geo points lik this.

[image]

i've calculate the distance using [How to calculate distance between two locations using their longitude and latitude value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu?rq=1)

My question is, when user stands near on "A" (start position), i want to tell the direction, you hav move to  "North","East","West","South"  like this,.

if user wrongly move other direction, Need to tell like "You hav mov wrong direction" and say correct direction.

How to get the direction between two geo points.?

I've get the degee  from [Get direction (compass) with two longitude/latitude points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502795/get-direction-compass-with-two-longitude-latitude-points?rq=1)

it returns some degree, But i'm unbale to tell the correct direction.

How to get the direction between two geo points.?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209899/determine-compass-direction-from-one-lat-lon-to-the-other

Answer (score 2):

check this method if it can help you:

```
location.getBearing()
```

[**Returns the direction of travel in degrees East of true North. If hasBearing() is false, 0.0 is returned.**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing%28%29)

Use this method or sensor for getting device's direction.

After that get the direction of your two points in degrees using this:

```
location.bearingTo(dest)
```

[**Returns the approximate initial bearing in degrees East of true North when traveling along the shortest path between this location and the given location. The shortest path is defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid. Locations that are (nearly) antipodal may produce meaningless results.**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29)