# Set compass direction in android

Tags: android

I want to show compass pointer which shows source to destination pointer of location.

**Compass pointer will point to destination pointer from current location.**

How can i implement this on my android app?

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-compass-code-example.html

Comment: I tried this but this changes direction based on sensor but i want to show direction from latitude and longitude of destination location.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209899/determine-compass-direction-from-one-lat-lon-to-the-other and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502795/get-direction-compass-with-two-longitude-latitude-points

Comment: Please see the posting guidelines for Stack Overflow and include some code that you've tried and errors/issues you're having. Thanks!